# Term for a fully connected balanced graph (Rock paper scissor)

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, game-theory

Is there a mathematical, graph theory, game theory term for a graph that is fully connected and balanced evenly with each other node.

I'm thinking in situations like Rock paper scissors where each action is equally balanced by each other option?

Comment: What you ask is not very clear. Perhaps this will help,though: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vertex-TransitiveGraph.html

Comment: A directed graph which is connected, and where every vertex has the same indegree and outdegree, is called Eulerian http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerianGraph.html . Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

A regular tournament $T=(V,E)$ is a complete digraph on $|V|=2n+1$ vertices where each vertex has the same score as each other vertex. Each vertex is connected to each other vertex by exactly one directed edge and each vertex dominates exactly $\frac{|V|-1}{2}$ other edges and is dominated by the $\frac{|V|-1}{2}$ other edges.